# Xcode crash report KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000100001da0

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, report, xdebug

I'm having a tough time figuring this crash report sent to me by Apple. For some reason they keep telling me that my app crashes on start but I cannot recreate the crash after testing it on different devices. As I'm not sure what's causing it to crash and not being able to recreate the crash, I was wondering if anyone can help shed some light on what the problem could be?

And some extra info, I'm using AsyncImageView 1.5.1 and the Reachability class. I'm not sure if that could be the source of the crash?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

```
OS Version:          iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000100001da0
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000194c880b4 objc_retain + 20
1   MyApp                           0x0000000100113274 0x1000f4000 + 127604
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100111a84 0x1000f4000 + 121476
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184324430 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001842637dc _CFXNotificationPost + 2056
5   Foundation                      0x000000018515b6bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
6   MyApp                           0x000000010011099c 0x1000f4000 + 117148
7   Foundation                      0x000000018524a7ec __NSThreadPerformPerform + 368
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184336320 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001843355c4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184333674 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184261660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
12  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d35f5a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
13  UIKit                           0x0000000188b664f4 UIApplicationMain + 1484
14  MyApp                           0x00000001000fab44 0x1000f4000 + 27460
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001952dea04 start + 0
```

Comment: Looks to me like you are not unsubscribing some class from NSNotificationCenter when it gets deallocated.

Comment: Hi borrrden thanks for the reply. I'm using a Reachability class by Tony Million. In it it uses NSNotificationCenter but I don't see it calling removeObserver anywhere in the class. Could that be the possible reason of the crash? Also do you know why it's working on my testing devices but not at Apple? Thanks!

Comment: First of all you need to symbolicate the crash report to get any useful info.  Those 0x1000f4000 + 127604 and stuff are *your* program, minus the symbol info.  Don't ask how here either please, it's been explained thousands of times on here.